# Postgresql 9.3 - JDBC connection error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

im trying to create a database connection between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. In this case, i have installed Postgresql on my Ubuntu System and change in 'postgresql.conf' the listen_addresses from 'localhost' to '*'. Next, i add 'host all all 192.168.2.1/24 md5' to the 'pg_hba.conf' file.

With this configuration it is possible to connect with the pgAdmin 3 to the database. But if im trying to connect with jdbc it doesn’t works.

Im using the versions - JDBC: '9.3-1103 JDBC 3', Postgresql: 9.3.

At first, i  built a little test project with basic code:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("user", "user");
    properties.setProperty("password", "pw");
    properties.setProperty("ssl", "true");

    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.2.143:5432/testdb";
    String driverJDBC = "org.postgresql.Driver";

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driverJDBC);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from testtable;");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this little programm produces the error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Der Verbindungsversuch schlug fehl.
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:240)
            at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:143)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.<init>(Jdbc3gConnection.java:24)
            at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:412)
            at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
            at db.DBConnection.make(DBConnection.java:23)
            at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:75)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried disable windows firewall, other JDBC version (4).

Maybe anyone has an idea?

Ps. Hope my English is ok ;)

Comment: Are you sure the PSQL server is running?

Comment: have you tried to connect from simple java app instead of from tomcat  (the stack trace looks like you are trying to connect from something running in tomcat)?

Comment: So you are connecting from 192.168.2.1, is that correct?

Comment: @mic4ael: yes i'm sure. I can connect without difficulty over pgAdmin 3.

Comment: @WeareBorg no from 192.168.2.139. But it's the same subnetwork (/24) or i'm wrong?

Comment: That#s what I was going to ask you, what is this /24 you have added, plus in postgres.conf, you have to add the allowed IP addresses which can connect. Temporarily you can set it to ALL.

Comment: @WeareBorg ok i try it. Can i write host all all all md5 or host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5?

Comment: No, just google it man how add allowed hosts in Postgresql. Es ist zu einfach.

Comment: @chuchichaeschtli yes your right ;). No i have only try it from tomcat but its a good idea.

Comment: In your postgresql.conf, there is list_address, you can change it to listen_addresses='*'   . This way it will listen from all IP addresses. Then issue sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart

Comment: @WeareBorg sorry your right ;). I have try it but nothing has changed.

Comment: Then you have to check Postgresql logs man, as soon as you connect, and there is a failure, Call tail -f /var/logs/syslog | grep postgres on ubuntu

Comment: @WeareBorg this things i have tried before i have write this post ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well `192.168.2.1/24` means 24 bits strict (24 bits are 3 bytes (24/8=3) so the first three numbers are strict, the `1` allowed to differ) so you need a client-ip from `192.168.2.XXX`.

If this does not work try to get informations from logging.

1. Edit the config file `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`. (Make a backup maybe)
2. Uncomment the line `#log_destination = 'stderr` and set destination to syslog `log_destination = 'syslog'`.
3. Save restart database-server.
4. Execute `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep postgres` and try to connect from client.

You should see something like this:

```
Oct  7 11:02:18 Ubuntu-1510-wily-64-minimal postgres[1732]: [4-1] 2019-10-07 11:02:18 CEST [1732-2] postgres@cms LOG:  connection authorized: user=XXX database=cms SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.2, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, compression=off)
```